# Is their a way to queue or automate particle bakes?

Tags: particles, baking

Is there a way to queue or automate particle bakes?

When multiple particle systems are used, it would be great to have a way to queue up the baking of each, and then leave the computer chugging. Possible?

Aftermarket add-on would be great, too, but the ones I have seen automate tasks like AO baking only.

Answer (score 2):

The bad news is, no.

The good news is, yes!

From [the Manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/physics/baking.html):

> **Bake All Dynamics**
>
> Bake all physics systems in the scene, even those of different types. Useful for baking complex setups involving interactions between different physics types.

So, you can't exactly queue, so if there's a specific order you want them to bake, I don't think that's possible without scripting your own solution.

But you CAN bake all the systems in the whole scene all at once by just clicking Bake All.

Comment: Thanks.... It would be handy to queue, but this wortks.... and I did not know that different physics types were baked together (which is to say I have been baking more than I needed to, it seems...).

Comment: Yup! Only bake what you need, if you can help it ;-)